# create views and triggers in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help with creating a view and then triggers for the following: **update salesperson commission(10% of sale), inventory quantity, and customer balance when each invoice line item is entered.**

This is what I have right now for the view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW NEW_INVOICE_LINE_ITEM 
AS
SELECT COMMISSION, INV_QUANTITY, CUSTOMER_BALANCE
FROM SALESPERSON, INVENTORY, CUSTOMER;
```

This is what I have for the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPDATE_COMMISSION
AFTER INSERT ON INVOICE_LINE_ITEM FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE SALESPERSON
SET COMMISSION = (SALE_PRICE * QUANTITY_SOLD) *.10
WHERE :NEW.COMMISSION = SALESPERSON.COMMISSION;
END;
```

I keep on getting the error: bad bind variable 'new.commission'

This my database schema below:

```
DROP TABLE PO_LINE_ITEM;
DROP TABLE PURCHASE_ORDER;
DROP TABLE VENDOR;
DROP TABLE INVOICE_LINE_ITEM;
DROP TABLE INVENTORY;
DROP TABLE INVOICE;
DROP TABLE SALESPERSON;
DROP TABLE CUSTOMER;
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(CUSTOMER_ID DECIMAL(2,0) PRIMARY KEY,    
CUSTOMER_NAME CHAR(25),
CUSTOMER_ADDRESS CHAR(15),
CUSTOMER_ZIPCODE DECIMAL(5,0),
CUSTOMER_CITY CHAR(15),
CUSTOMER_STATE CHAR(2),
CUSTOMER_BALANCE DECIMAL(4,2)
);
CREATE TABLE SALESPERSON
(SALESPERSON_ID DECIMAL(3,0) PRIMARY KEY,
SALESPERSON_NAME CHAR(25),
COMMISSION DECIMAL(5,2)
);
CREATE TABLE INVOICE
(INVOICE_ID DECIMAL(3,0),
CUSTOMER_ID DECIMAL(2,0),
SALESPERSON_ID DECIMAL(3,0),
ITEM_NUM DECIMAL(4,0),
INVOICE_DATE DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (CUSTOMER_ID, SALESPERSON_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER,
FOREIGN KEY (SALESPERSON_ID) REFERENCES SALESPERSON
);
CREATE TABLE INVENTORY 
(INV_NUM DECIMAL(4,0) PRIMARY KEY,
DESCRIPTION CHAR(10),
INV_QUANTITY DECIMAL(4,0),
INV_PRICE DECIMAL(7,2),
INV_COST DECIMAL(7,2),
INVOICE_ID DECIMAL(3,0),
ITEM_NUM DECIMAL(4,0),
FOREIGN KEY (INVOICE_ID, ITEM_NUM) REFERENCES INVOICE
);
CREATE TABLE INVOICE_LINE_ITEM
(QUANTITY_SOLD DECIMAL(4,0),
SALE_PRICE DECIMAL(7,2),
INVOICE_ID DECIMAL(3,0),
INV_NUM DECIMAL(4,0),
ITEM_NUM DECIMAL(4,0),
PRIMARY KEY (INVOICE_ID, INV_NUM, ITEM_NUM),
FOREIGN KEY (INVOICE_ID, ITEM_NUM) REFERENCES INVOICE,
FOREIGN KEY (INV_NUM) REFERENCES INVENTORY
);
CREATE TABLE VENDOR
(VENDOR_ID DECIMAL(2,0) PRIMARY KEY,
VENDOR_NAME CHAR(25),
CITY CHAR(15),
STATE CHAR(2),
VENDOR_BALANCE DECIMAL(4,2)
);
CREATE TABLE PURCHASE_ORDER
(PURCHASE_ORDER_ID DECIMAL(2,0) PRIMARY KEY,
BALANCE DECIMAL(4,2),
SHIPMENT CHAR(10),
PURCHASE_ORDER_DATE DATE,
VENDER_ID DECIMAL (2,0),
FOREIGN KEY (VENDER_ID) REFERENCES VENDOR
);
CREATE TABLE PO_LINE_ITEM
(PO_DATE DATE,
PO_BALANCE DECIMAL(4,0),
ITEM_NUM DECIMAL(4,0),
INV_QUANTITY DECIMAL(4,0),
INV_NUM DECIMAL(4,0),
PURCHASE_ORDER_ID DECIMAL(2,0),
PRIMARY KEY (INV_NUM, PURCHASE_ORDER_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (INV_NUM) REFERENCES INVENTORY,
FOREIGN KEY (PURCHASE_ORDER_ID) REFERENCES PURCHASE_ORDER);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which client are you using? SQL Developer sometimes does that when you use the wrong method of running the code, but I can't remember off-hand which way round it is. If you're using 'run statement' then try 'run script', and vice versa. If that doesn't help add the structure of both tables to the question. What is the relevance of the view, and why doesn't it have any join conditons (or, indeed, proper joins)?

Comment: `invoice_line_item` doesn't have a `commission` column... are you supposed to find the sales person from the parent invoice? And are you replacing their current commission, or adding to it?

Comment: I'll just comment that this is a bad use of triggers. This should be in an application procedure.  To say nothing of the fact that it looks very buggy.  Think carefully about that WHERE condition .  You are updating every salesman's commission whose current commission = the calculated value.  I doubt that is what you

Comment: Yes I want to find sales person from the parent invoice table and replace the current commission. do I need to put a commission column in `invoice_line_item`

Answer (score 0):

Table `invoice_line_item` does not contain column `commission`, this is the reason for *bad bind variable* error. You should rewrite your trigger code like here:

```
create or replace trigger update_commission
  after insert on invoice_line_item for each row
begin
  update salesperson sp
     set sp.commission = sp.commission + (:new.sale_price * :new.quantity_sold * .1)
   where sp.salesperson_id =
         (select salesperson_id
            from invoice i
           where i.invoice_id = :new.invoice_id);
end;
```

In your `view` you did not attach conditions how to join tables, here is the example how to do this:

```
create or replace view vw_invoices as 
  select ili.invoice_id, ili.quantity_sold, ili.sale_price, 
         i.salesperson_id, sp.salesperson_name
    from invoice_line_item ili
    join invoice  i on i.invoice_id = ili.invoice_id
    join salesperson sp on sp.salesperson_id = i.salesperson_id;
```

Depending on which informations you want to show - connect proper tables and use correct joins.

Comment: I got it working but it shows me that i have error in line 8:

Comment: new post has been posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36903748/sql-trigger-for-view