# SQL Trigger for View

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, sql-view

I need help with creating a view and then triggers for the following: update salesperson commission(10% of sale), inventory quantity, and customer balance when each invoice line item is entered.

This is what I have right now for the view:
I got it working but it shows me that i have error in line 8:

```
    CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(CUSTOMER_ID DECIMAL(2,0) PRIMARY KEY,    
CUSTOMER_NAME CHAR(25),
CUSTOMER_ADDRESS CHAR(15),
CUSTOMER_ZIPCODE DECIMAL(5,0),
CUSTOMER_CITY CHAR(15),
CUSTOMER_STATE CHAR(2),
CUSTOMER_BALANCE DECIMAL(4,2)
);
CREATE TABLE SALESPERSON
(SALESPERSON_ID DECIMAL(3,0) PRIMARY KEY,
SALESPERSON_NAME CHAR(25),
COMMISSION DECIMAL(5,2)
);
CREATE TABLE INVOICE
(INVOICE_ID DECIMAL(3,0),
CUSTOMER_ID DECIMAL(2,0),
SALESPERSON_ID DECIMAL(3,0),
ITEM_NUM DECIMAL(4,0),
INVOICE_DATE DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (CUSTOMER_ID, SALESPERSON_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER,
FOREIGN KEY (SALESPERSON_ID) REFERENCES SALESPERSON
);
CREATE TABLE INVENTORY 
(INV_NUM DECIMAL(4,0) PRIMARY KEY,
DESCRIPTION CHAR(10),
INV_QUANTITY DECIMAL(4,0),
INV_PRICE DECIMAL(7,2),
INV_COST DECIMAL(7,2),
INVOICE_ID DECIMAL(3,0),
ITEM_NUM DECIMAL(4,0),
FOREIGN KEY (INVOICE_ID, ITEM_NUM) REFERENCES INVOICE
);
CREATE TABLE INVOICE_LINE_ITEM
(QUANTITY_SOLD DECIMAL(4,0),
SALE_PRICE DECIMAL(7,2),
INVOICE_ID DECIMAL(3,0),
INV_NUM DECIMAL(4,0),
ITEM_NUM DECIMAL(4,0),
PRIMARY KEY (INVOICE_ID, INV_NUM, ITEM_NUM),
FOREIGN KEY (INVOICE_ID, ITEM_NUM) REFERENCES INVOICE,
FOREIGN KEY (INV_NUM) REFERENCES INVENTORY
);
CREATE TABLE VENDOR
(VENDOR_ID DECIMAL(2,0) PRIMARY KEY,
VENDOR_NAME CHAR(25),
CITY CHAR(15),
STATE CHAR(2),
VENDOR_BALANCE DECIMAL(4,2)
);
CREATE TABLE PURCHASE_ORDER
(PURCHASE_ORDER_ID DECIMAL(2,0) PRIMARY KEY,
BALANCE DECIMAL(4,2),
SHIPMENT CHAR(10),
PURCHASE_ORDER_DATE DATE,
VENDER_ID DECIMAL (2,0),
FOREIGN KEY (VENDER_ID) REFERENCES VENDOR
);
CREATE TABLE PO_LINE_ITEM
(PO_DATE DATE,
PO_BALANCE DECIMAL(4,0),
ITEM_NUM DECIMAL(4,0),
INV_QUANTITY DECIMAL(4,0),
INV_NUM DECIMAL(4,0),
PURCHASE_ORDER_ID DECIMAL(2,0),
PRIMARY KEY (INV_NUM, PURCHASE_ORDER_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (INV_NUM) REFERENCES INVENTORY,
FOREIGN KEY (PURCHASE_ORDER_ID) REFERENCES PURCHASE_ORDER);

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_INVOICES
  2  AS
  3  SELECT INVOICE_LINE_ITEM.INVOICE_ID, INVOICE.SALESPERSON_ID,
  4   SALESPERSON.SALESPERSON_NAME, SALESPERSON.COMMISSION,
  5   INVENTORY.ITEM_NUM, INVENTORY.INV_QUANTITY,
  6   INVOICE.CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_BALANCE
  7  FROM INVOICE_LINE_ITEM, INVOICE, SALESPERSON, INVENTORY, CUSTOMER
  8   JOIN INVOICE ON INVOICE.INVOICE_ID = INVOICE_LINE_ITEM.INVOICE_ID
  9   JOIN SALESPERSON ON SALESPERSON.SALESPERSON_ID = INVOICE.SALESPERSON_ID
 10   JOIN INVOICE ON INVOICE.ITEM_NUM = INVENTORY.ITEM_NUM
 11   JOIN CUSTOMER ON CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = INVOICE.CUSTOMER_ID;
 JOIN INVOICE ON INVOICE.INVOICE_ID = INVOICE_LINE_ITEM.INVOICE_ID
                                      *
ERROR at line 8:
ORA-00904: "INVOICE_LINE_ITEM"."INVOICE_ID": invalid identifier
```

Comment: You do not have table `INVOICE_ID`.

Comment: What database are you using, Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: see errors now at line 8

Comment: First make up your mind which database you want to use.

Comment: I'm using oracle sql

Comment: I think this is just a matter of being accurate. Please check names, make sure all tables are created and you reference the tables and columns using correct names. This is something so very basic and should work. Oracle should allow to create views like this. The other question may be not directly related to the issue is the following. Why do you list tables twice in the `FROM` list?

Comment: I didn't realize your only suppose to list one. how do you know which one to list?

Answer (score 1):

You have splited `JOIN` syntax between tables with `comma` which caused this error, so you should modify your sql.
Try this, may work;)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_INVOICES
AS
SELECT INVOICE_LINE_ITEM.INVOICE_ID, INVOICE.SALESPERSON_ID,
  SALESPERSON.SALESPERSON_NAME, SALESPERSON.COMMISSION,
  INVENTORY.ITEM_NUM, INVENTORY.INV_QUANTITY,
  INVOICE.CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_BALANCE
FROM INVOICE_LINE_ITEM
JOIN INVOICE ON INVOICE.INVOICE_ID = INVOICE_LINE_ITEM.INVOICE_ID
JOIN SALESPERSON ON SALESPERSON.SALESPERSON_ID = INVOICE.SALESPERSON_ID
JOIN INVENTORY ON INVOICE.ITEM_NUM = INVENTORY.ITEM_NUM
JOIN CUSTOMER ON CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = INVOICE.CUSTOMER_ID;
```

About oracle `JOIN`, please see this [Joins](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm), or you could just use `where` clause instead of `JOIN`

Comment: Why is this? Can you please explain?

Comment: Because the join condition (`ON` clause) must immediately follow the `JOIN`.

Comment: does it matter which table you put with the FROM clause?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be **INVOICE_LINE_ITEM.INVOICE_ID** in the query

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_INVOICES
 AS
 SELECT INVOICE_LINE_ITEM.INVOICE_ID, INVOICE.SALESPERSON_ID,
 SALESPERSON.SALESPERSON_NAME, SALESPERSON.COMMISSION,
 INVENTORY.ITEM_NUM, INVENTORY.INV_QUANTITY,
 INVOICE.CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_BALANCE
 FROM INVOICE_LINE_ITEM, INVOICE, SALESPERSON, INVENTORY, CUSTOMER
 JOIN INVOICE ON INVOICE.INVOICE_ID = INVOICE_LINE_ITEM.INVOICE_ID
 JOIN SALESPERSON ON SALESPERSON.SALESPERSON_ID = INVOICE.SALESPERSON_ID
 JOIN INVOICE ON INVOICE.ITEM_NUM = INVENTORY.ITEM_NUM
 JOIN CUSTOMER ON CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = INVOICE.CUSTOMER_ID;
 JOIN INVOICE ON INVOICE.INVOICE_ID = INVOICE_LINE_ITEM.INVOICE_ID
```

Comment: does anyone know what is wrong with this?  `intPosition = (SequentialSearch(fstrContractType, strCriteria);`